# How can I find the mean value of a column having two elements Weekday and Weekend

Tags: mean

SyntaxError: unmatched ']'

The above error message was returned

#get the mean delivery time on weekdays and print it
mean_delivery_time_on_weekends = df['day_of_the_week'] = 'Weekend'][delivery_time].mean()),'minutes'

This is my input